# Get n from findelement in findelements iteration

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm searching an element inside elements list. And if an element found I return the n of iteration.

I'm wondering is there is another faster way to do that? Currently I can do that purpose this way. But it takes time to process.

```
var iBtnFix = 0;
var elProfiles = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("xxx"));   // list 

for (var i = 0; i < elProfiles.Count; i++)
{
    try
    {
        elProfiles[i].FindElement(By.XPath(".//button[contains(@class,'yyy')]"));
        iBtnFix = i;
                                
        break;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of the `listHaveFollowBtn` variable if it is not accessible outside of the `for`?

Comment: thank you. edited the code. how about the question?

Comment: If you would post the relevant HTML and tell me which element you want, I'm pretty sure I can write a locator to find that element without looping. From what you have posted, I think a CSS selector, `.xxx button.yyy`, would work. `.` in a CSS selector means class and a space is descendant, the equivalent of `//` in XPath.

Comment: i can find that button directly without iteration. but what i need is to find (var i) on which list is the button located? because i want to use it on another block.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use if-else condition with return statement instead of try-catch block. You can create method isElementVisible() which return boolean based on visibility of element and use its response in your if condition.

For example :

```
if(isElementVisible("your locator")
{
    return index;
}
```

Method for example :

```
public boolean isElementVisible(By by){

        boolean isElement = false;
        try{
            isElement = driver.findElement(by).isDisplay();
        }catch(NoSuchElementFoundException e){
            isElement = false;
        }
        return isElement;
    }
```

This is java code. You can write according in C#.

Comment: Added method in above comment itself. you can get idea from there. Hope it helps you.

Comment: The method itself is using try catch. Is there any speed effect by creating a separate method? beside the method can be reusable.